# How to embed an animation in the following into .pdf using latex?

Tags: manipulate, animation, latex

How to embed an animation in the following to `.pdf` file using latex? Is it possible to add the buttons for j and k such as in `Manipulate`?

```
    \[Psi][x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x < 1/2}, {-1, 1/2 < x <= 1}}]
\[Psi][j_Integer, k_Integer, x_] := \[Psi][2^j x - k]
Manipulate[
 If[k > 2^j - 1, k = 2^j - 1];
 Plot[\[Psi][j, k, x], {x, -0.05, 1.05},
  Exclusions -> None,
  Filling -> Axis,
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Italic]},
  PlotLabel -> Subscript[\[Psi], j, k][x],
  ImageSize -> {500, 350},
  ImagePadding -> {{10, 20}, {10, 10}}],
 {{j, 0, Style["j", Italic]}, Range[0, 4], SetterBar},
 {{k, 0, Style["k", Italic]}, Range[0, 2^j - 1], SetterBar},
 SaveDefinitions -> True, AutorunSequencing -> {1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but check out this link:  https://www.12000.org/my_notes/Mathematica_animation_into_PDF_using_latex/index.pdf#:~:text=The%20goal%20is%20to%20embed%20in%20a%20pdf,Live%20distribution%20to%20compile%20the%20LATEX%EF%AC%81le%20to%20pdf.

Comment: Also, when I initially tried the example above, pdflatex failed to compile the code.  After some searching:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605396/why-wont-animate-package-work  I found out my TeX distribution was outdated.  Had to execute the MikTex console (described in the link) to update MikTex.  AFter which the PDF example was successfully compiled.

Comment: In your first solution, the buttons for j and k can not be added. So, we can change just one parameter (j or k) in the animation.